# Firestore security rules: compare arrays of map

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am writing a security rules for user. And I want for users to be able to updated only certain parts in their profile, like country, city, street, name, surname. 
But I want to restrict their access to update reviews (which is an array of maps) about them. It's fairly easy to check if user is trying to overwrite simple field values, but is it possible to somehow compare arrays of map? 
One way to restrict user access would be to create a different collection for reviews, but I would prefer to keep it in one place, to avoid extra reads. I realize that comparing arrays of map could be too much for firestore, but I want to make sure if it is possible or not.

Something like:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow update: if isAuthorized() && request.resource.data['reviews'] == resource.data['reviews'];}
```

[DB model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhtpw.png)

Comment: Right now you have to compare all known fields against each other to see if something changed.  The Firebase team is working on ways to make this sort of diffing easier.

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson !

As this is what the product allows to do as of this moment, would you mind posting your comment as an answer to give it more visibility over the community?